# What does the CSS3 style grid-column-start: 2; does?

Tags: css, grid-layout, col

What does the CSS3 style `grid-column-start: 2;` do?

Please try to answer from the following:

• Generates grid with 2 columns

• Creates a grid item on second column

• Starts grid item from second column

• Creates a 2×2 grid

Comment: starts grid item from second column

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a homework answering service. We won't perform your work for you. If you have a specific problem that we can help out with, please mention what the problem is. In this case, the problem seems to be that you don't know how to search the Internet?

Comment: Are you just trying to guess it from the name ?

Answer (score 0):

It determines a grid item's location within the grid by referring to specific grid lines.
**grid-column-start/grid-row-start** is the line where the item begins, and **grid-column-end/grid-row-end** is the line where the item ends.

For Your case suppose following css property

`.item-a{
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: five;
    grid-row-start: row1-start
    grid-row-end: 3
 }`

The output will be [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56m8e.png)

- Starts grid item from second column